# Add div to modal window

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, window

I'm creating a table containing some nodes. When I click on a particular node in the table a modal window opens(in this modal window i need to insert the data I have stored in a div).

```
/*each node is a hyperlink and has the "#animatedModal" href, and also a different id*/

var b = document.querySelectorAll("a");
        b[i].setAttribute("id", i);
        b[i].setAttribute("href", "#animatedModal");



 /*when a particular node is clicked, the getEndpoints function is called*/
 $("a").click(function(test) {
        getEndpoints(test.target.innerHTML);//innerHTML= node id number
    });
```

The getEndpoints function gather node info from a server and inserts the data into the div

```
function getEndpoints(nodeid) {
$.get( "http://.../node/" + nodeid, function( node ) {
    window.data = node;
    var key = ["epid", "clslist", "loc", "name", "type", "zplus"];
    var endpoints = node.endpoints[0];
        for(var k = 0; k < key.length; k++){
            $("#" + key[k]).text(endpoints[key[k]]); //this selects each id from the div(the id is the same as the key) and adds the value from the server to each key)
        }
   })}
```

This div is always displaying information for the node that has been clicked. e.g.: If i press the 1st node, the div shows the info for the 1st node and so on.

```
<div id="endDiv">
    <ol>
        <li><label>epid: </label><span id="epid"></span> </li>
        <li><label>clslist: </label><span id="clslist"></span> </li>
        <li><label>loc: </label><span id="loc"></span> </li>
        <li><label>name: </label><span id="name"></span> </li>
        <li><label>type: </label><span id="type"></span> </li>
        <li><label>zplus: </label><span id="zplus"></span> </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

The modal window is created with this function:

```
function createModal() {
var content = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'modal-content'
})
var createAnimation = $('<div/>', {
    id: 'animatedModal'
});
var closeAnimation = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'close-animatedModal'
});
$(".table-fill").append(createAnimation);
$("#animatedModal").append(content).append("CONTENT HERE");
$("#animatedModal").append(closeAnimation);
$(".close-animatedModal").append(closeAnimation).append("PRESS TO CLOSE");
```

So, instead of "CONTENT HERE", I want my modal window to display the div with the node info.

I tried those but without any results:

```
$(".modal-content").append("#endDiv");
```

and

```
var divInfo = document.getElementById("endDiv").textContent;
 $("a").on( "click", function() {
   $(".modal-content").text(divInfo) );
 });
```

Can someone help me with this?